# ssh to server and switch user and then run multiple commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

In a script, I am trying to ssh from within and then switch user and then trying to run multiple commands.

Can you please help me out with this?

Below is the example:

```
ssh $a@$e << EOF        
sudo su hbase << EOF    
echo "list '"$tID":.*' " | /ignio/hbase/bin/hbase shell &> ListOutput

cat ListOutput | grep "^"${tID}":" >ListOfTable

while read line; do

echo $line

tableName=`echo $line | cut -d':' -f2`

/hbase/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver import $tID:$tablename hdfs:///backup/${tID}

EOF

EOF
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of asking for "help with this", you should present an acctual question relating to the difficulty you are having.

Comment: Why not login as the correct user in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have passwordless sudo configured:

```
ssh user@host 'sudo -u sh -c hbase "command1;command2;command3"'
```

It may be better to put all the remote commands into a script then just run:

```
ssh user@host 'sudo -u hbase /some/script'
```